# How to pass value to custom annotation in java?

Tags: java, spring

my custom annotation is:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CacheClear {

    long versionId() default 0;
}
```

I want to achieve something like this, in which I can pass the method param "versionTo" to my custom annotation.

```
@CacheClear(versionId = {versionTo})
public int importByVersionId(Long versionTo){
    ......
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: The retention runtime, only says that you can use reflection to evaluate whether the method has an annotation or not. You can not give it parameters

Comment: AOP can help you, have a look at AspectJ and this blog post for example: https://blog.jayway.com/2015/09/08/defining-pointcuts-by-annotations/.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's *not* possible.

Annotations require constant values and a method parameter is dynamic.

Comment: Sad story 

Answer (score 7):

You cannot pass the value, but you can pass the path of that variable in `Spring Expression` and use **AOP's** `JoinPoint` and `Reflection` to get and use it. Refer below:

Your Annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CacheClear {

    String pathToVersionId() default 0;
}
```

Annotation Usage:

```
@CacheClear(pathToVersionId = "[0]")
public int importByVersionId(Long versionTo){
    ......
}
```

Aspect Class:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class YourAspect {

   @Before ("@annotation(cacheClear)")
   public void preAuthorize(JoinPoint joinPoint, CacheClear cacheClear) {
      Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
      ExpressionParser elParser = new SpelExpressionParser();
      Expression expression = elParser.parseExpression(cacheClear.pathToVersionId());
      Long versionId = (Long) expression.getValue(args);

      // Do whatever you want to do with versionId      

    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone who wants to do something similar.