# How to pass the value from Pathvariable to a custom Validator in springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-validator, spring-validation

I am having a custom Validator as follows:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = CountryValidator.class)
public @interface ValidCountry {

    String message() default "Invalid country";

    String language() default "";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};


    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}

public class CountryValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidCountry, String> {

  

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidCountry constraintAnnotation) {
        ConstraintValidator.super.initialize(constraintAnnotation);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String inputCountry, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        //validation logic
    }

}
```

And the controlller method

```
 @PutMapping("/operation/{language}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> doOperation(@PathVariable("language") String language, @Valid @RequestBody PayloadDTO payload) {


        System.out.println("Done");
        return ResponseEntity.accepted().body(null);
    }
```

Now i want to validate a field inside PayloadDTO using @ValidDate annotation. And i want the language to be taken from the Pathvariable. Is there anyway to achieve this? Something like this

```
PayloadDTO{

@ValidCountry(language = <language from pathvariable>)
private String country;

}
```

Comment: You can use SpringBoot AOP. example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51845624/14032355

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was achieved by autowiring HttpServletRequest bean in validator class and fetching pathvariable from the bean.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a custom validator class instead of using field annotations.

```
@Component
public class PayloadDTOValidator implements Validator {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return PayloadDTO.class.equals(clazz);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        PayloadDTO payload = (PayloadDTO) target;

        //Retrieve path variable from request context
        HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
        String language = request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE).get("language");
        
        //Your validation logic
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to achieve validations using annotations